# Pushing input to seperate DOTenv file from function

Tags: python

I'm in python.
How would I go about writing a function that takes in a name and then a value?
How do I push input to another file?

What I tried:

```
global key
key = ""
print(key)
# print("Key must be string.\n Key must have a length greater than or equal to 3.\n Key will be displayed in capital letters.")

def getKey(key:str="", value:str="") -> str:
  # Check type of key
  if(type(key) != str or type(value) != str):
    print("Type of key and value  must be a string.")
    getKey(key,value)
  # Check length of key and valuee
  if(len(key) < 3 and len(value) < 1):
    print("Length of key and value  must be 3 or more.")
    print("An error has occured.\n Fix it yourself damnit")
    getKey(key,value)

def appendKeyToDOTenn():
  # .ENV.APPEND(KEY) AS KEY,VALUE.. Help
```

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried already? Asking questions without giving proper context makes it hard for us to answer properly.

Comment: I really do not have a clue. I can try to code something for it to show what I want it to do. Check edit in post

Comment: Asking the user for input, adding inputs to a dictionary, and writing it to a file is exhaustively covered in other posts. [Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) _Specific_ questions about your code are allowed here. "I can't figure out how to implement this function, so do it for me" is not allowed, because SO isn't a free online code-writing service.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I found literally no help on this though.

Comment: How would I get data by either input or by it as a parameter and add it to a .end file and have it be correct? As in the key would actually be the key and the value the value

Comment: I literally don't know where to look for help on this. I'm new, im not sure what it's even called. What would I search for?

Comment: Google don't know what im trying to describe, because I don't know HOW to explain in

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you're defining some environment variables in the Python script and want to dump them to a `.env` file, i.e. in the form of lines in format `KEY=VALUE`? If that is the case then you essentially just have to google for how to do each of the specific things you'll need to do, i.e. (1) concatenate strings (`key`, `"="`, `value`) and (2) write lines to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `getKey` function that you defined is also accepting and returning the `value`. So, I'm assuming that—

- You want to insert the `key` and `value` as parameters of the function.
- Do a bunch of validations like type checking and length checking.
- Return both the `key` and `value` if they pass the validation.

Then in the second function—

- You want to take the `key` and `value` from the return values of the first function.
- And send those to a second function that will append them as `KEY=VALUE` to a `.env` file.

Since the first function is taking both the `key` and `value` as parameters, let's rename the function. Also, I assumed that you'll appreciate simplicity over brevity at this point.

```py
# In Python, it's canonical to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`.
def get_key_value(key: str, value: str) -> str:
    """This function gets the key for you."""

    # Check the type of the key using `isinstance` rather than `type`.
    if not isinstance(key, str):
        # Raising error as early as possible is considered idiomatic.
        raise TypeError("Type of `key` must be string.")

    # Doing the same for the value.
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        raise TypeError("Type of `value` must be string.")

    # Doing the length checking.
    if not len(key) >= 3:
        raise ValueError("Length of the `key` cannot be less than 3.")

    if not len(value) >= 1:
        raise ValueError("Lenght of `value` cannot be less than 1.")

    return key, value
```

Now, you can send the return values of the first function to the following function. This one will open a `.env` file in **append-only** mode and append the `key`, `value` in a newline.

```py
def append_key_value_toenv(key, value):
    """This function appends key, value to the environment file."""

    # Open / create and open the .env file.
    with open("./.env", "a") as envfile:
        # Write your variables.
        print(f"Appending {key=}, {value=} to the environment file.")
        envfile.writelines([f"{key}={value}\n"])
```

You can tie together everything in the following way:

```py
# script.py

# In Python, it's canonical to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`.
def get_key_value(key: str, value: str) -> str:
    """This function gets the key for you."""

    # Check the type of the key using `isinstance` rather than `type`.
    if not isinstance(key, str):
        # Raising error as early as possible is considered idiomatic.
        raise TypeError("Type of `key` must be string.")

    # Doing the same for the value.
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        raise TypeError("Type of `value` must be string.")

    # Doing the length checking.
    if not len(key) >= 3:
        raise ValueError("Length of the `key` cannot be less than 3.")

    if not len(value) >= 1:
        raise ValueError("Lenght of `value` cannot be less than 1.")

    return key, value


def append_key_value_toenv(key, value):
    """This function appends key, value to the environment file."""

    # Open / create and open the .env file.
    with open("./.env", "a") as envfile:
        # Write your variables.
        print(f"Appending {key=}, {value=} to the environment file.")
        envfile.writelines([f"{key}={value}\n"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    key, value = get_key_value("HELLO", "WORLD")
    append_key_value_toenv(key, value)
```

When you run the script, you'll see a `.env` file created in your current directory (if it already doesn't exist) and the file will have a new line as `HELLO=WORLD`.

Comment: Thank you. Before this I started making my own, simple version of this. It kinda sucked though. A couple of questions though, why "isInstance" and not "type"? What's the difference between them? Also, when appending to .env. You wrote "{key=}" and "{value=}". Why is that? Why not just "{key}" or "{}" with a .format function after?

Comment: `isinstance` is a little faster than `type` and also it's the recommended way of checking the type of an object in Python. And notice that the string is inside an `f`. F-string is a neat feature to do string interpolation in Python. Try removing the `=` sign and see what happens to the output.

Comment: Oh okay, ill remember that when validating next time. I see, what's the difference? Assuming it has something to do with the curly braces?

Comment: From what I can tell, It don't change anything

Comment: Nope...if you write `f'{foo=}'`, it'll print `foo=value` but if you type f'{foo}`, it'll just print `value`.